# How to access control from parent aspx from its child ascx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, ascx, findcontrol

I try to access the MainContentBlock control from the aspx, but unable to do so.

In the aspx file I have registered both controls:

```
<uc3:ContentBlock ID="MainContentBlock" runat="server" DynamicParameter="id" DefaultContentID="3951" /></uc3>

<uc3:childshow ID="Childshow" runat="server"/></uc3>
```

In the code behind for child.ascx

```
If Me.Parent.Page.FindControl("MainContentBlock") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.MainContentBlock.Item.Id = 4357 Then
```

...

But the error says BC30456: 'MainContentBlock' is not a member of 'child'.

It's almost like the ".parent" part did not work.

However, If I try the following:

```
If Me.Parent.MainContentBlock IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.MainContentBlock.Item.Id = 4357 Then
```

...

It will bring up the error "BC30456: 'MainContentBlock' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

and seems it at least recognized the .parent part again.

confused... please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to reference MainContentBlock as a property of the child control. When you use `Me.MainContentBlock`, `Me` refers to the child control.

You just need to use FindControl, and properly reference the found control:

```
Dim myBlock As ContentBlock = TryCast(Me.Parent.FindControl("MainContentBlock"), ContentBlock)

If myBlock IsNot Nothing Then
    'do things with myBlock
End If
```

Comment: Hi, but I have added .Parent.FindControl() ? I thought this would access the parent aspx file? Sorry still confused...

Comment: FindControl may find the control, but that doesn't change the reference or attempted reference to Me.MainContentBlock.

Comment: no problem. I added some sample code. In general you need to try to find the control and assign it to a variable. Then access it as needed. Sample isn't tested but general idea is there. Don't know what type the MainContentBlock is. Assumed `ContentBlock`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the control is located on the page, you may need to find it recursively, but in a simple situation you would just do this:

```
var pnl = Page.FindControl("MainContentBlock") as Panel; //or whatever it is
if (pnl != null)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Here's a recursive method if you need it:

```
public Control FindControlRecursive(string controlID, Control parentCtrl)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentCtrl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == controlID)
            return ctrl;
        FindControlRecursive(controlID, ctrl);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
var pnl ((PageName)Page).FindControlRecursive("MainContentBlock") as Panel;
```

Comment: Hi James, Thanks, I think I manage to let the child find the control in aspx. However, I also want to access the property of that user control, such as:

If Me.Parent.FindControl("MainContentBlock").EkItem IsNot Nothing Then....

Where EkItem is a property of the control. I could not access EkItem at this point since it gives me the error:

BC30456: 'EkItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Anything I did wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` works but the pain is that what you're looking for can be higher then just at parent level. Here is a handy method I use:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
        return root;

    foreach (Control ctl in root.Controls)
    {
        Control foundCtl = FindControlRecursive(ctl, id);

        if (foundCtl != null)
            return foundCtl;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the control. But do you know how could I also access its property? For example: Me.Parent.FindControl("MainContentBlock").EkItem
Where EkItem is a property of the user Control. The above line gives me an error : BC30456: 'EkItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: To answer previous comment: type casting